# mysql: encrypting and decrypting data

Tags: mysql, encryption

Does mysql provide a mechanism for storing and retrieving encrypted data? I don't mean passwords, I mean real strings.

I'd like to encrypt a string, store in mysql and then retrieve the decrypted string at a later date.

So, I know there is the AES_Encrypt and decrypt functions. But they ask for a key. (which is fine) but I wondering if you call those functions and use your user password as the key. Or something else that is super-simple.

Also, is there a simple wrapper for the AES_Encrypt & decrypt functions in Rails? Or do you need to build the query manually?

Comment: Why do you need such unusual thing?

Comment: don't want to store some data as plain text on the drive or in the db. Not passwords so the standard encrypt & match won't work.

Comment: What's wrong with plain text? Everyone uses it without any problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you, then all you need is a method to generate an AES key from your (or other) user password?

Shouldn't you be asking 'Is there an easy method to generate an AES-key from 5-20char string'?

As you point out, the other tools are already in place in mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/encryption-functions.html

Also you might find some ideas in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237816/mysql-encrypted-columns) post here on SO.

Answer (score 5):

You can just concat the encrypt functions:

```
select aes_encrypt('MyData',Password('MyPassword'))
```

and back again..

```
select Aes_decrypt( aes_encrypt('MyData',Password('MyPassword'))
     , Password('MyPassword'))
```

Comment: Be sure to re-encrypt the original data if the password is about to change.

Answer (score -4):

```
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO testperson (name,password,contact) VALUES('$name',md5('$pass'),$cont)";
```

Just write md5 before the input you want to encrypt, like password.

Comment: MD5 is not an encryption algorithm. *Never* use MD5 to "encrypt" passwords.