# How to encrypt a specific column in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, encryption, phpmyadmin

I am experimenting with creating a simple message system (PHP) page that uses a MySQL table to store the entries. The rough outline of the columns I'll use in the table are:

**msg_id** (primary key, auto_increment)

**user_id** (foreign key pointing to the user who created the message)

**time** (a DATETIME entry to provide msg timestamps)

**msg** (a VARCHAR containing the msg)

**accessable** (just an int(1), 0 means no one except the user himself can read the msg, and 1 means others can read it)

What I'm wondering is, what's the best way to encrypt the **msg** field so prying eyes can't read it (let's say, by opening the mysql CLI or phpMyAdmin and just read the value stored in a row)?

If "accessable" is set to 0, then only the user him/herself should be able to read it (by accessing some PHP page), but if set to 1, everyone else should be able to read it as well. I don't know how to tackle this, so any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Look here for list of possible encryption functions:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html

You can create trigger for update and check there field `accessable`. Something like that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER crypt_trg BEFORE UPDATE ON table FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF new.accessable = 0 THEN
    SET new.msg := ENCRYPT(new.msg, 'key');
  ELSE
    SET new.msg := DECRYPT(new.msg, 'key');
  END IF;
END;
```

You also can update all existing records in you table with this query:

```
UPDATE table SET msg = IF(accessable = 0, ENCRYPT(msg, 'key'), DECRYPT(msg, 'key'));
```

So you can select records for you PHP code:

```
SELECT msg_id, user_id, time, IF(accessable = 0, DECRYPT(msg, 'key'), msg) msg
FROM table
```

**UPD.** Also here was similar question:

[MySQL encrypted columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237816/mysql-encrypted-columns)

Comment: isn't it a bit weird to put the key in the trigger? if one get access to the db, he'll be able to see the key and decrypt the data...

Comment: I agree with @Roey passing key in trigger, will make all thing of no use.

Comment: also, if you rely on triggers, if the database is set to log queries, it will be captured in plain-text, making the encryption useless ( see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/writing-logs-into-tables/ ) . Best option is application level encryption, which is what @Core Xii is broadly mentioning in his answer.

Comment: The ENCRYPT() function is deprecated in MySQL 5.7, are removed in MySQL 8.0, and should no longer be used. For one-way hashing, consider using SHA2() instead. According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encrypt

Answer (score 13):

You can also encrypt the data prior to the query to insert it, so that MySQL doesn't even *know* it's encrypted, and decrypt it on retrieval in the application. For that, you should store it in a varbinary or blob column though.

Comment: A blob sounds like a decent data type for this particular usage area. If I may ask, could you perhaps clarify your first sentence? By using blobs, how would the decryption take place? If the MySQL admin knows that the datatype is a blob, can't he/she just decrypt it manually to read the contents?

Comment: Encryption - If you know the key, you can decrypt the data. If your MySQL admin has access to the key used to encrypt the information then of course he can also decrypt it. That's true for _every_ method you might use. As to how you endecrypt, that depends entirely on your application and the functionality it provides, and what algorithms you choose to use.

Answer (score -2):

So I had an idea that might accomplish this, but it's all conceptual.

Suppose that you had the value "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", and you wanted to do a search for "lorem". One way is that you could take the original and break it up into chunks (lowercased), and put them in a second table. The whole (original) value is in the original table column with row_id 123, but a new table called "chunks" might have:

```
row_id | chunk | foreign_row_id
1      | lo    | 123
2      | or    | 123
3      | re    | 123
4      | em    | 123
5      | m     | 123
6      |  i    | 123
7      | ip    | 123
```

Think of it like a substring index, where every substring is 2 characters long.

Now, when a user wanted to perform a search, you would similarly chunk that up, then do a lookup. If they typed "`lo`", then you see which foreign row IDs matched. But if they enter "`lore`", then you do a search for all foreign row IDs that had a matching chunk for "`lo`", "`or`", AND "`re`".

So far, not too practical. However, if the original value "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" is encrypted or hashed, then you could ALSO chunk up the 2-char substrings, encrypt/hash them, then do a lookup on the chunks *instead* or the full string. No decryption or unhashing necessary.

The logic would be:

1. Chunk the search string
2. Encrypt/hash each 2-char chunk
3. Do the lookup and find all encrypted/hashed chunk matches.

Any match can then be fetched from the original table. This would protect the data at rest, because if the chunk table was compromised, they can't do anything with a bunch of encrypted/hashed 2-char values. You can't take 2 encrypted/hashed substrings and recombine them or get anything meaningful from them.

If I am the inventor and got to name this, since it's similar but not quite the same as making a Rainbow Table, I would called this "Fruity Pebbles Tables". Because of the chunks.

Comment: I think a better name for a design like this might be a 'Cocoa Puff Table' because it's all-out "cuckoo"!

Comment: the time and space complexity for this is out of the charts... it's not practical. Also, the original question was around encryption, not searching over and encrypted column.

Comment: additionally, your search will fail very often: splitting "lorem ipsum dolor" in chunks (length does not matter), you end up with a unique list like `do ip lo m  r re su`. Now if you search for "ore", you'd split it up into `e or`, resulting in no matches. a solution would be to split it with every possible offset, so you search for `or e AND o re`, but the amount of combination rises exponentially and as you see, you still have a non satisfying result.

Comment: @AdrianB. I came up with this when considering protecting PII fields, like name and email, while leaving larger columns unencrypted. Thus, it didn't need to be efficient. Just searchable via partial matching, and encrypted at rest. As for the original question, it wasn't about searching encrypted data, but I came across this answer when trying to see how to do that on the free version of MySQL, so when I thought of my own approach, I decided to contribute it here for posterity.

Comment: @DesertEagle in the scenario where you search on an input with 3 characters, you would search for just the encrypted string of "lo" and "or". Why would you search for an encrypted single char, if all entries are of 2-char chunks?