# MySQL Column for Encryption

Tags: mysql, encryption

I need to build a small private app. I want to store a piece of personally identifiable information (it's an internal account number -- not an SSN or anything like super-sensitive) in a table that "encrypts" it.

I put encrypts in quotes because I wish the data to be stored as follows:

- stored in a way that if someone physically looked at the table data the piece of info would not be discernible
- stored in a way that if someone did a simple query select the resulting data output would not not be discernible
- yet when I write my own query select statement I can still decrypt the data and present it in a readable fashion

In other words, I want it only moderately encrypted so that I can still decrypt it and read it. I know MD5 hashing locks the value from ever being read. I want something less than that.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encrypt a specific column in a MySQL table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275882/how-to-encrypt-a-specific-column-in-a-mysql-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MD5 is **NOT** encryption. It's hashing.

If you don't mind passing the crypt key around in each query, it's trivial to have this in MySQL:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(crypted_field, 'crypt key goes here') AS decrypted
```

and

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (crypted) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('some string', 'crypt key'));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is "Symmetric Key Encryption". You can use a key to encrypt your data, and the same key to decrypt it as needed (as opposed to a hash function which as you said - makes the original data irrecoverable). In MySQL I would take a look at the [AES_Encrypt and AES_Decrypt functions.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html). Hopefully that gets you pointed in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

MySQL provides both [DES and AES encryption](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html).  You will need to figure out key management, but the encryption algorithms are available.