# password protect a field in table #mysql

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I am working on an examination project!
I am in search of some technique to password protect a ***longblob*** field in mysql database.
This field is used to store question papers.
I want to make it in such a way that even if someone hacks into my database, he cannot access the field unless he has a special passkey/password.

Comment: So you are trying to enforce Confidentiality (i.e. encrypting longblobs) but leaving alone Availability and Integrity (i.e. assuming someone can access the db)? There's absolutely no point in making this until you enforce first the communication link between the application and the database. It's like putting jail bars to a tent window ;)

Answer (score 1):

The concept 'password protect' is really 'encryption' with an encryption key.

Presumably your mysql database is already password protected, both the server it's on and the database logon itself.  However, to provide additional security, you can store a field with encryption.

Is the MySQL DB on a server, or is it on the same machine as you're going to access it with?  If it's the latter, you need to encrypt it in some fashion that does not involve storing the encryption key on the same machine (as if they've found their way into your machine, they could find the encryption key).  See [How to encrypt a specific column in a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275882/how-to-encrypt-a-specific-column-in-a-mysql-table) for more specific details.  Just don't store 'key' on the database server - either store it on a separate application server, or on paper :)

Comment: actually my DB would be on the same server as on which I would host my  application.
Ain't there any way of locking a table by simply using a passkey for restricting access to the table?

Comment: That's not exactly what you asked in the original question - Table != Field.  There is of course a method of limiting access to a table (limiting access to certain users - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/security.html for example).  However, you're imagining someone hacking into your database; if so, it seems to me they're likely to be using a privileged account (very often, an administrator's account, if they find a security flaw in MYSQL).  So you're still better off encrypting the field with an AES encryption key that is stored elsewhere.

Comment: Yes actually either of the two will work for me (locking table or field).
Can u share some link on how to use AES for this kind of problems?

Answer (score 0):

You could go with AES or DES encrypt/decrypt. Keep the key in application code

[encryption functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html)

Note that DES requires some SSL to be compiled into the binary.

Comment: I want to use a random and different key every time I want to access the field. Is it possible?

Comment: It is but where would you store it? If you store it close to the encrypted field everyone can decrypt it as you just gave them the key. It would be like hanging the (random) key next to it's lock.

Comment: Yeah I got your point!
But I am still very much confused how to implement this.
It would be so gr8 of of u if u would share some link regarding the implementation here.