# How to encrypt sql Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, encryption

How do I encrypt sql tables? Any help will be appreciated. 
I am starting my encryption on file(items) upload from txt file.

My idea is like this:

## global.php

```
$config["encode_key"] = "T07EGsS123123";
```

## fileupload

```
 $sql = "UPDATE " . $config["table_items"] . " SET itemContent = AES_ENCRYPT('$content', '$config[encode_key]')
```

and after it I must show the items using decrypt with config key.

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: How do I encrypt sql tables? My Idea was like that, but not sure how can I finish it to prevet any data to be stolen.

Comment: why do you want to store the key in db ?

Comment: how can I secure my db from getting stolen? This is only way I know.

Comment: no one could get into your db when you didnt change the mysql config files

Comment: so nothing can be done with mysqldump or simple injection?

Comment: how could someone do a dump without login details ? sql injections belongs to userinputs most time, so if you dont have a form everything is fine

Comment: The only form is Login/register to site and contact form.

Comment: then show us the code and we can tell you if its safe or not

Comment: just let me know which one.

Comment: everything you think we should check

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to encrypt a specific column in a MySQL table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275882/how-to-encrypt-a-specific-column-in-a-mysql-table)